# How to search and find application in Non - English language in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I can find my app when I search about it in English and using the same bundle key (ex: tawfeercom )

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faris_and_hasan.tawfeercom1

The app targeting Jordanian store and they use Arabic language as from right to left language. But you wont be able to find it with its title when you past this (توفيركم‎) in search bar.

Everything look normal to me in store listing and custom store listing, but I couldn't figure out how!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you will have to follow to achieve the same. Sometimes you will have to wait util your app gets search ranking.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

[image]

The explanation is quiet clear to follow. Hope this helps.

You can check Supported languages for confirmation about the availability of language you are using.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en&ref_topic=3450769

[image: Supported Languages]